# Aplicação cliente no Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Minha aplicação é uma aplicação cliente onde consome uma API Proxy e mostra os dados recebidos em 'ejs'.

Porém ao fazer deploy no Heroku, quando tento acessar a url apresenta a mensagem abaixo:

> 2018-11-06T17:10:10.423095+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/users/simonjefford/detail" host=shawandpartners-cli.herokuapp.com request_id=538b1d06-c096-4c1f-95ec-e87823a08f7f fwd="191.35.57.193" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https

OBS.: Na minha máquina local, a aplicação funciona perfeitamente

Comment: e qual é o funcionamento normal? Você poderia informar ?

Comment: Ele encontra o caminho "/api/users/simonjefford/detail" e retorna os dados normal... Porém consegui resolver, é que na página tinha um arquivo que ele busca na internet e estava em HTTP e como o link é em HTTPS, por motivos de segurança tive que alterar para HTTPS tbm